# on recomposition collectAsStateWithLifecycle() returns old data from old StateFlow

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

collectAsStateWithLifecycle() returns old value from old recomposition. is there anyway to fix this? In my case, on every recomposition if data changes, i create new model object and that has initialized MutableStateFlow. on every recomposition collectAsStateWithLifecycle() return old object value instead of new flow . is there a way to fix this?
note: replacing MutableStateFlow with MutableState works as expected.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.lifecycle.compose.collectAsStateWithLifecycle
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import timber.log.Timber
import java.util.Timer
import java.util.TimerTask
import kotlin.random.Random

fun timerRepeat(delay: Long, runnable: suspend () -> Unit) {
    Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                runnable()
            }
        }
    }, 0, delay)
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {

//    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
//        Navigator(ImageListScreen()) {
//            CurrentScreen()
//        }
//    }

    val flow = remember {
        val flow = MutableStateFlow(0)
        timerRepeat(1000) {
            flow.value = flow.value + 1
        }
        flow
    }

    TestContainer(flow = flow)
}

@Composable
fun TestContainer(flow: StateFlow<Int>) {
    val value = flow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
    TestWidget.Widget(count = value)
}

open class Initializer {
    private var objectId = Random.nextInt(100, 200)
    private var update = 0
    val initialized: StateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("Initializer.$objectId.${update++}")

    fun initComplete() {
        (initialized as MutableStateFlow).value = "Initializer.$objectId.done"
    }

    fun isInitialized(): Boolean {
        return initialized.value.contains("done")
    }
}

abstract class Widget : Initializer() {
    private var objectId = Random.nextInt(100, 200)

    abstract fun init()

    @Composable
    protected abstract fun build()

    @SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
    @Composable
    fun Content() {
        val value = super.initialized.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
        Timber.v("[$objectId] initialized.value:$value, isInitialized():${super.isInitialized()}")

        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        scope.launch {
            init()
            initComplete()
        }

        if (value.contains("done")) {
            this.build()
        }
    }
}

class TestWidget(private val count: Int) : Widget() {
    companion object {}

    override fun init() {
    }

    @Composable
    override fun build() {
        Text("Hello $count")
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestWidget.Companion.Widget(count: Int) {
    val widget = remember { mutableStateOf(TestWidget(count)) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = count, block = {
        widget.value = TestWidget(count)
    })

    widget.value.Content()
}
```

here is sample logs

```
29426-29426 Widget                  in.cjcj.jcp                          V  [196] initialized.value:Initializer.100.0, isInitialized():false
29426-29426 Widget                  in.cjcj.jcp                          V  [127] initialized.value:Initializer.100.done, isInitialized():false
29426-29426 Widget                  in.cjcj.jcp                          V  [173] initialized.value:Initializer.165.done, isInitialized():false
```

code that prints log

```
val value = super.initialized.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
Timber.v("[$objectId] initialized.value:$value, isInitialized():${super.isInitialized()}")
```

initialization is considered done if initialized value contains done. calling manually .value return the right value but collectAsStateWithLifecycle return old object value (edited)

Comment: Where did you learn, to use Kotlin for android development?

Comment: Hi this is jetpack compose framework. I have learned throw youtube videos

Comment: Thanks. I know what jetpack compose is, but I have no idea how to use it :P